# superimposing plots (generated by plotLMER.fnc)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to superimpose plots for 2 lmer-generated models (representing 2 levels of a conditions under which all the other conditions are nested) but ggplot returns an error that's beyond me to understand.  If ggplot2 is not the right tool to use, could somebody suggest an alternative that would deal neatly with differences in range (for ylimit), please?

```
> plot1 <- plotLMER.fnc(datPrH.lmer11, pred="L1", intr=list("Word.Order",     levels(dat$Word.Order), "end"), addlines=TRUE)
> plot2 <- plotLMER.fnc(datPrM.lmer11, pred="L1", intr=list("Word.Order", levels(dat$Word.Order), "end"), addlines=TRUE)
> ggplot(plot1 + plot2)
```

Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

Comment: You should name the required packages to build your plots. It seems likely that the plot1 and plot2 objects are not of gglot-class. Perhaps lattice objects?

Comment: `plotLMER.fnc` is from the `languageR` package. It has an `addToExistingPlot` argument which could be useful ...

Comment: your `plot1` and `plot2` appear to be identical.  If you can't see that `addToExistingPlot` solves your problem, could you post a reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) ?